# remove everything from a url redirect to doc root

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url say https://example.com/index.php/foo/bar

I want any page in example.com to goto https://example.com

I want the browser to update with the home url. this is for any url to hit this site. This could include urls with query ie https://example.com/?foo=bar. Literally all/any pages to go to the home page regardless

I've tried numerous RewriteRules Redirects and none do what i want (the nearest is to load index.php but the url is still wrong)

I'd like to use .htaccess but if easier in .conf file I'd do that

Just thinking I could do this in the index.php file by checking reloading the page with header if it has a query on it. would this be recommended?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 apache 2.4 and i have php 7.1 with all mods enabled to handle redirection and rewrites (site had wordpress on it but now contains a coming soon page and nothing else)

current but not working version in htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Make sure there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*  /? [R=301,L]
```

this will correctly load a url with a query string (https://example.com?foo=bar) but the browser doesn't update the redirected url/ if I use https://example.com/index.php/foo/bar scripts and images in the index.php are not loaded and as with query strings the url remains unchanged in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following to the top of my index.php resolved my issue without needing edits to .conf or .htaccess files

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/index.php' ) {
    header("Location: /index.php");
    exit(0);
}
```